# Inductive proof that an n-cube is bipartite

Tags: graph-theory, induction

For all $n\geq1$.

I am aware of the other proof where we assume sets with even number of 1's and odd number of 1's. I did an inductive proof and don't know if it is correct.

When $n=1$, it is trivial. When $n=2$, we have a square, which is a cycle of even length, so bipartite.

Can we say that for all $n\geq3$, the resulting n-cube is composed of squares and since we have established that squares are bipartite, the n-cube is also bipartite?

Comment: This looks a harder approach to me.  You say "composed of squares" but topologically there are also hexagons etc. How do you prove there are no pentagons without considering the parities of the number of $1$s or something equivalent?

Comment: It seemed to me that incrementing $n$ will duplicate the current n-cube and then connect the corresponding (adjacent?) vertices. Such connection seems to only add squares (or at least a trapezoid, which will still be bipartite). What case will we get a pentagon or higher? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Dimension_levels.svg

Comment: As an example the path $(0,0,0) \to (1,0,0) \to (1,1,0) \to (1,1,1) \to (0,1,1) \to (0,0,1) \to (0,0,0)$  could be seen as a hexagon.  You can easily show there is no pentagonal path using a parity argument, but perhaps not easily otherwise

Answer (score 2):

Your argument would be partially correct but that wouldn't be an induction proof. However we can do one:

As you said, for $n = 1$, it is trivial. Now, suppose inductively it holds for $n$, i.e. $n$-cube is bipartite. Then, we can construct an $(n+1)$-cube as follows: Let $V(G_n) = \{v_1,...,v_{2^n}\}$ be the vertex set of $n$-cube. Since $(n+1)$-cube has $2^{n+1} = 2\cdot2^n$ vertices, copy $G_n$ and call it $G_n'$, and let $V(G_n') = \{v_1',...,v_{2^n}'\}$. Now, in order to construct $(n+1)$-cube, we should connect $v_i$ to $v_i'$ for all $1 \le i \le 2^n$.

Now by induction hypothesis, $G_n$ is bipartite. Let $A$ and $B$ be bipartition sets of $G_n$ and $A'$ and $B'$ be bipartition sets of the copy $G_n'$ (because by induction hypothesis, $G_n'$ is bipartite as well). Now notice that there is no edge from $A$ to $B'$ and similarly $A'$ to $B$. Therefore, we can partition vertex set of $G_{n+1}$ into two as $A \cup B'$ and $A' \cup B$ and we are done.

Comment: Yes, I didn't do the full induction - just wanted to know if that square reasoning can indeed by used. Would $n=1$, which would be a single edge, be sufficient to hypothesize that $n$-cube is bipartite? By that logic, wouldn't every graph with edges be bipartite?

Comment: Hypothesis is not for $1$-cube. It's just the base case for the induction. Hypothesis is for $n$- cube, which we assume $n$-cube is bipartite. Then if we can prove it for $n+1$, we can conclude that $n$-cube is bipartite for all $n$.

Comment: In this case, we could also take $n=2$ as the base case. But while doing induction, we either assume it for $n$ or everything up to $n$ and prove it for $n+1$. Trying to prove it for $n$ by just assuming for $n=2$ is not induction at all.

Comment: Can we not independently show the case when $n=1$ and then alter the question and induct for $n\geq2$ or use the stronger form of induction? Because using just the case when $n=1$ doesn't seem to justify that the nth case will also be true. If we use the $n=1$ case only, wouldn't we be hypothesizing that the nth cube will be bipartite just because a single-edge graph is bipartite? Wouldn't every graph be bipartite by that logic (since every graph is made up of lots of single edges?) I'm sorry if I'm sounding confusing.

Comment: No, you are not confusing, I understand your question very well. But the thing about induction is, we don't prove induction hypothesis by using the base case. As its name suggests, *hypothesis*. So we are **assuming** that our argument is correct for $n$. We don't have to prove our assumptions but we can use our assumptions to prove our general argument.

Comment: By the way it doesn't mean that we can't use $n=1$ and $n=2$ as base cases. But also notice that the way a graph is constructed is also important. We also construct $2$-cube from $1$-cube in the same way. And the way we add edges determines whether the graph we constructed is bipartite or not. Otherwise, if we take a disconnected graph $G$ with two components, where each component is bipartite, of course $G$ is also bipartite. But we can't use an argument like "if we start from edge, then wouldn't all the graphs be bipartite" since we are also adding some edges to our construction.

Comment: Haha yeah I forgot we don't need to extend the hypothesis from the base case.  So I don't even need to use squares? How sound will the square argument be though? Can that argument used for a proof?

Comment: I can't think of a way of using *only* the squares to prove this argument. As I said, we are also adding some edges while constructing an $n$-cube from squares. For instance think about $3$-cube. We construct it by connecting two squares with $4$ edges right? And the way we add these edges may change the graph being bipartite or not. That's why I have written a paragraph about how $(n+1)$-cube can be constructed from $n$-cube.